# Why am I getting uneven vertical padding in a Motif Widget List?

Tags: c, unix, x11, motif

I am using a Motif Widget Scrolledlist. The list is created as follows:

```
/* COMMAND GROUP LIST */
ac = 0;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNselectionPolicy, XmSINGLE_SELECT); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNtopAttachment, XmATTACH_WIDGET); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNtopWidget, printer_menu_button); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNleftAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNrightAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNbottomAttachment, XmATTACH_POSITION); ac++;
XtSetArg(al[ac], XmNbottomPosition, 50); ac++;
command_group_list = XmCreateScrolledList(form, "command_group_list", al, ac);
XtManageChild(command_group_list);
```

the items are added by a callback function when the printer is selected. from the routine adding the items the only relevant Motif-related commands are:

```
XmListDeleteAllItems(command_group_list);
...
str = XmStringCreateLocalized(command_group_line);
XmListAddItem(command_group_list, str, 0); 
XmStringFree(str);
```

However, when I display the list I get a weird bottom padding, seems like the height of each individual item of the list is larger than the height of the text. This can be seen in this image:

[image: Motif Widget List]

While in the documentation (for example O'Reilly Volume Six A) the list's items appear to have a "normal" height. I do not know what there could be missing. I have reviewed if the sample code in 6A apply more resources to the list but I can not find anything.

For example, this list screenshot, extracted from [6A](http://www.ist.co.uk/motif/books/vol6A/ch-13.fm.html#418303) shows how the height is what you would normally expect in a list:

[image]

I am using FreeBSD and OpenMotif 2.3.8_1.

Could it be a font issue?

UPDATE: this is the whole routine that adds the items, as stated above, the only Motif/X11 code are the Xm functions deleting all items and adding individual items in a for loop.

This is the routine which populates the items (note that mostly is C code non-related to the actual Motif issue):

```
/* THIS FUNCTION READS COMMAND GROUPS USED BY THIS PRINTER */
void read_command_group(char *printer_name) {

    /* BUILD FILE PATH */
    char filepath[256];
    strcpy(filepath, "/etc/xcmdprinter/");
    strcat(filepath, printer_name);

    /* OPEN AND READ FILE */
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        if(line[0]=='G') {
            XmString str;
            char command_group_line[256];
            int i=2;
            while(line[i]!='\0') {
                command_group_line[i-2] = line[i];
                i++;
            }
            command_group_line[i-2] = '\0';
            str = XmStringCreateLocalized(command_group_line);
            XmListAddItem(command_group_list, str, 0); 
            XmStringFree(str);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

}

/* CALLBACK FUNCTION FOR PRINTER SELECTION */
void select_printer(Widget w, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data) {

    XmListDeleteAllItems(command_group_list);
    read_command_group((char *)client_data);
}
```

Comment: Without knowing your widget hierarchy, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks @tofro. Could you help me to better understand what does "widget hierarchy" mean? What information do you think it shall be included? I have updated the message with the code used to create the list. The items are added using just `XmListAddItem`.

Comment: Ah. Now I got it. You're complaining about the height of a single list item, not about the height of the  list itself. Motif will use the height of the largest entry for all entries. Can you show the code that populates the list? The example you showed is definitely not the code that produced the image. And it's pretty normal that Motif is a bit grateful on size when you use a fixed font.

Comment: I have updated the message with the code that populates the list. It uses only `XmListAddItem` and is invoked as part of the callback of the "Select Printer" Option Menu. Before using `XmListAddItem`, `XmListDeletaAllitems(command_group_list);` is also called.

Comment: I have also updated the question, it was misleading as it was not clear that the issue is with the individual height of each list item.

Comment: You might want to play with XmListSpacing (the spacing between items in the list)

Comment: @quasimodo XmList wouldn't support multi-line entries by default.

Comment: @quasimodo Well spotted, the items contained a trailing `\n`- removing it makes the extra padding disappear.

Comment: On a separate note, I am also wondering why the focus is displayed with such a strong dotted line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item contains a newline character; remove it.

> I am also wondering why the focus is displayed with such a strong dotted line.

That is set by the list widget's resource [`XmNhighlightThickness`](http://www.vaxination.ca/motif/XmPrimitive_3X.html#XmNhighlightThickness),
whose default value is 2.